# HTML to database transmission automation

Tags: html, ajax, database, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I've been playing around with web-developement for a while.
Transmitting data between a html-form and a database appears to be a common issue.
I usually solve this problem by an ajax call to a php script, as shown here in the image below.

This seems to be a lot of work, cause you need to code at four different scripts (html, js, php, sql).

The only interesting thing that changes from request to request is the type and name of the attributes to be submitted.

Is there a more efficient way handling this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don’t really need JavaScript to pass the data to the server, as the HTML form can do that on its own, so I would narrow down the layers to 3:

- Presentation (front end)
- Data access (back end)
- Database

So then the question becomes, *can you manage user input without one of these layers*? The short answer is no, not with current web development paradigms, to the best of my knowledge.

On a tangent, one way to mitigate the overhead of interacting with the layers is to use one language from end to end, like the MEAN stack does. In MEAN, your front end is written in JavaScript, as well as your server side code. At a database level, MongoDB stores the data in JSON-like schemas. Consequently, you reduce the gymnastics needed to change data from one format to another, as your data passes through the layers.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the data to server without JavaScript and without reloading the page?

Comment: Entirely without JavaScript? I don't think so, but you could do it with minimal JS by targetting the `onsubmit` attribute of the form.